# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, localstorage

у меня есть массив,который я беру из localStorage с помощью такого кода

```
function loadCart(data) {
//проверяю есть ли в localStorage запись cart
if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
    // если есть - расширфровываю и записываю в переменную cart
    cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        if(isEmpty(cart)){
            $('.main-cart').html('Корзина пуста');
        }
        else init();
}
else {
   $('.main-cart').html('Корзина пуста');
}
```

}

после этого загружаю ассоциативный массив с товарами из бд

```
function init(){
$.post(
 'pages/adminPage/core.php',
{
    "action":"loadGoods"
},
showCart
);
}
```

и вывожу товар из localStorage

```
        function showCart(data) {
var pack= JSON.parse(data);

var out = '';
    for (var id in cart) {
        for (key in pack) {
            if(id===pack[key].id){
                out += `<button data-id="${id}" class="del-goods">x</button>`;
                out += `<img src="pages/orderPage/goods/${pack[key].img}" 
                width='50em' height='50em'>`;
                out += ` ${pack[key].name  }`;
                out += `  <button data-id="${id}" class="minus-goods">- 
      </button>  `;
                out += ` ${cart[id]} `;
                out += `  <button data-id="${id}" class="plus-goods">+ 
      </button>  `;
                out += cart[id]*pack[key].cost;
                out += '<br>';
            }
        }
    }
$('.main-cart').html(out);
$('.del-goods').on('click', deleteGoods);
$('.plus-goods').on('click', plusGoods);
$('.minus-goods').on('click', minusGoods);
}
```

Проблема в том,что когда я выполняю ф-цию minusGoods

```
function minusGoods(){
//уменьшает товар в корзине на 1
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
if (cart[id]===1){
    delete cart[id];
}
else cart[id]--;
saveCart();
showCart();
```

}

вылетает эта ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
Скорее всего я неправильно делаю, пожалуйста подскажите в чем проблема

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`showCart` вызывается без параметров, следовательно во время выполнения значение параметра `data` - будет `undefined`.

Далее идет попытка вызова

```
data=JSON.parse(data);
```

что в данном случае эквивалентно

```
data=JSON.parse(undefined);
```

`undefined` преобразовывается в строку `"undefined"` - и идет попытка разобрать данную строку как JSON.

В итоге закономерная ошибка:

```js
try {
  JSON.parse('undefined');
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e + '');
}
```

---

Для решения нужно просто передать параметр в функцию. Исходя из предоставленного кода, что-то вроде:

```
showCart(cart[id]);
```

Либо проверять внутри функции передан параметр или нет:

```
if(!isEmpty(cart) && data){
```

---

И как альтернатива - использовать для инита и обычной работы - разные функции.

Comment: я поставил параметр showCart(cart[id]); в ф-ци delete и plus, а так же проверку, теперь все работает,но id изменяется только после перезагрузки страницы

Comment: @КириллЧетвертков, а что находится в `cart[id]`? По предоставленному коду непонятно. Сейчас ты передаешь его как `data` - который ожидаешь как JSON, в котором массив. Судя по всему - это не совсем то, что ты хотел :-)

Comment: в cart[id] находится id товара из массива, из localstorage, сейчас вроде все как я хотел,но блин с перезагрузкой только

Comment: @КириллЧетвертков, на самом деле нет, так как внутри `showCart` ты используешь `data[id].cost` и `data[id].name`, и если у тебя в `cart[id]` число - то на попытке получить указанные значения ты должен был упасть, как как у числа нет индекса `id` и соответственно у полученного `undefined` Нельзя получить cost и name - будет исключения. Про изменение `id` непонятно - в функции ты заново выводишь весь список, это значит какие у тебя реально есть Товары в корзине - те и выводятся.

Comment: я изменил код, добился вроде чего хочу, то есть прибавляет id,но когда уменьшаю на один, ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Comment: @КириллЧетвертков, `ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` - почему такая ошибка - уже описано в ответе :-)

Comment: спасибо за помощь,удачи вам во всем)