# Проблемы с JSON на NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, json

Стандартный код для преобразования данных с MySQL запроса в JSON формат, но он у меня не работает:

```
http.createServer((request, response) => {
    const result = database.getData("tableNames");
    console.log(result);
    
     var resultArray = Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));
    
     resultArray.forEach(function(v){ console.log(v) });
    
    response.end('odd'); 
}).listen(3000);
```

Содержимое метода getData:

```
     function getTableNames(){
        var returnValue;
        
        con.query("SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'storagedb'", function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            returnValue = result;
        });
        
         return returnValue;
 }
 



 function getData(arg){
      switch(arg){
          case "tableNames" : return getTableNames(); break;
          default : return 404;
      }
 }
```

Консоль выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

```
undefined:1
undefined
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Server.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Lecht\Documents\Warehouse\WareHouse Server\server.js:14:39)
```

Содержимое result выглядит так:

```
[
  RowDataPacket { TABLE_NAME: 'движение товара' },
  RowDataPacket { TABLE_NAME: 'получатели' },
  RowDataPacket { TABLE_NAME: 'поставщики' },
  RowDataPacket { TABLE_NAME: 'приход' },
  RowDataPacket { TABLE_NAME: 'расход' },
  RowDataPacket { TABLE_NAME: 'справочник товаров' }
]
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно извлечь JSON с этого запроса?

Comment: `result` это строка с указанным содержимым? Если так, то не должно быть упомянутой ошибки, но код выглядит лишённым смысла (в resultArray будут просто отдельные символы строки).

Comment: где-то как-то так получается, что result равен undefined. @Grundy хорошо объяснил https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/883027/2659 откуда берётся `Unexpected token u`

Comment: На счёт undefined мне известно. JSON всё равно не парситься из JSON.Stringify(result). При JSON.parse выдаёт undefined, что странно. И да содержимое Result указано в последнем участке кода.

Comment: А что выводится, если вставить `console.log(result)`?

Comment: заверните вызовы в trycatch, поставьте отладочную печать, проследите за правильной обработкой асинхронных вызовов и найдёте причину. с тем, количеством кода, что вы выложили, можно сформулировать _только_ [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1288741/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d1%81-json-%d0%bd%d0%b0-nodejs#comment2273022_1288741) ответ

Comment: Содержимое result при выводе с помощью console.log:
 `[
  RowDataPacket { TABLE_NAME: 'движение товара' },
  RowDataPacket { TABLE_NAME: 'получатели' },
  RowDataPacket { TABLE_NAME: 'поставщики' },
  RowDataPacket { TABLE_NAME: 'приход' },
  RowDataPacket { TABLE_NAME: 'расход' },
  RowDataPacket { TABLE_NAME: 'справочник товаров' }
]`

Comment: у вас как минимум два вызова

Comment: Кинул оставшееся строки кода, проверьте

Comment: `getTableNames` асинхроннная, при таком использовании она всегда __вернёт__ undefined

Comment: А можно совет? Как правильно сделать?

Comment: Прочитайте ответ по [ссылке выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/) и перестройте код. То есть или вставляйте последующую логику внутри колбека, в котором получаете результат асинхронного вызова, или меняйте всё на промисы и async/await, если возможно. Это короткий ответ. Но чтобы понять его смысл, нужно разобраться в асинхронности. Например, тут: https://learn.javascript.ru/async (или в оригинале https://javascript.info/async). Первая глава уже немного поможет.

Comment: присоединяюсь. я бы посоветовал чуть более ссылок: https://learn.javascript.ru/callbacks, https://learn.javascript.ru/promise-basics, https://learn.javascript.ru/async-await

Comment: Ещё из того раздела может пригодиться https://learn.javascript.ru/promisify, если библиотека для базы данных не имеет API с промисами и захочется сделать вручную.

Comment: "Ещё из того раздела может пригодиться...", для mysql есть https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2

Comment: Решил проблему, дело было в асинхронности getTableNames()

Comment: каким способом решил?

Comment: Через callback. Синхронизировал так.